# Failure to get Active directory user list in Keycloak with a Ping Federate OpenID connector

Tags: active-directory, keycloak, openid-connect, pingfederate

**Software version :**

KeyCloak 15.0.2

**Configuration :**

***One realm active :***

- Enabled option set "on"
- Client Protocol is "OpenID-Connect"
- Access type is "public"
- standard Flow Enabled is "on"
- Direct Access Grant enabled

Everything else if off

In the "Keys" tab of the Client, nothing is set... ( might be related to my problem... )

***OpenID connector configuration *: **

- Enabled 'on'
- Store Tokens 'on'
- Store Tokens readable 'on'
- An authorization URL is set ( tested with the ping command )
- a Token URL is set
- the client Authentication is set to "Client sent as basic auth"

***Problem description :***

Purpose :

set a connexion between Keycloak an Windows Active Directory via Ping Federate

Step to achieve intended goal :

As stated in the title,

I created an OpenIDConnector in PingFederate to access the Active Directory databae of my organisation.

I added it into the "IDentity Providers" section of My Keycloak

I get a connexion to a Ping Federate login Window wherein I can type my AD credentials.

What I get :

From there on, i got an error seemingly from the Keycloak side of the system :

[Click here to see the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UITnk.png)

From what I gather from my research on the internet, something could be amiss in a configuration file for the Jboss server associated to Keycloak.

specifically in the standalone.xml configuration file.

I don't know Zilch about Keycloak ( beyond the basic ) and even less about Jboss but i would be grateful to any clue to help me :

1 - understand the problem ( how to set detailed log for jboss in Keycloak for instance )

2 - solve it wether in the form of a proper answer or more realistically as hint, indication of other forum wherein to ask my question etc...

Thank you.